# How can I open multiple json files in Python with a for loop?

Tags: python, json, for-loop

For a data challenge at school we need to open a lot of json files with python. There are too many to open manually. Is there a way to open them with a for loop?

This is the way I open one of the json files and make it a dataframe (it works).

```
file_2016091718 = '/Users/thijseekelaar/Downloads/airlines_complete/airlines-1474121577751.json'

json_2016091718 = pd.read_json(file_2016091718, lines=True)
```

[Here is a screenshot of how the map where the data is in looks (click here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ok49z.png)

Comment: Yes, just list all json files in the directory, and iterate through the json files to open them @thijstue, check my answer below!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use [os.listdir](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir) to list all the json files in your directory, create the full path for all of them and use the full path using [os.path.join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) to open the json file

```
import os
import pandas as pd
base_dir = '/Users/thijseekelaar/Downloads/airlines_complete'

#Get all files in the directory

data_list = []
for file in os.listdir(base_dir):

    #If file is a json, construct it's full path and open it, append all json data to list
    if 'json' in file:
        json_path = os.path.join(base_dir, file)
        json_data = pd.read_json(json_path, lines=True)
        data_list.append(json_data)

print(data_list)
```

Comment: Dear Devesh, thanks for your answer, I already came very close to what I wanted to achieve, but it only returned a dataframe with the last json file. Is there a way to have one big dataframe with all json files?
I already tried this but it returns only a line:

Comment: base_dir = '/Users/thijseekelaar/Downloads/airlines_complete'
json_data_firstmonth = pd.DataFrame()

#Get all files in the directory
for file in os.listdir(base_dir):

    #If file is a json, construct it's full path and open it
    if 'json' in file:
        json_path = os.path.join(base_dir, file)
        json_data = pd.read_json(json_path, lines=True)
        json_data_firstmonth = pd.concat([json_data_firstmonth, json_data])

Comment: Can you please update what you observed in the question itself!

Comment: When I did it exactly your way, it only returned a dataframe with the data of the last json file in it

Comment: Check the updated code, `data_list` should contain a list with all dataframes! @ThijsTUE

Comment: And then translate it into a dataframe? I will try, thanks

Comment: You can iterate through all dataframes from `data_list` and do whatever you want to do with it! Also if the answer helped you, it will be great if you could mark it as accepted @ThijsTUE :)

Comment: It worked when we did it another way, thanks tho for all the help Devesh!

Comment: Great! Thanks for the upvote! Glad that I was able to help you lead  in  the correct direction!

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```py
import os

# not sure about the order
for root, subdirs, files in os.walk('your/json/dir/'):
    for file in files:
        with open(file, 'r'):
            #your stuff here
```